# Why is my html code not displayed?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging, jinja2

I added a logo image and then the code below, in the `header` section, is no longer displayed when the html is viewed. The new image seems to overlap the old content. What changes should I make?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-IN" class="js">
<head>

    <link href="/static/css/koolindex_in.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/css/common_in2.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/static/css/list_in2.css?{{VERSION}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
{% include "kooltopbar.html" %}


<div id="wrapper">
        <h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext"></h1>




    <header>  

        <nav class="navbar nohistory">
            <ul class="inlined">
                <li>
                    <a href="/">{% trans %}Home{% endtrans %}</a>
                </li>                 


                <li class="current">
                    <a href="/customer_service.htm">{% trans %}Customer Service{% endtrans %}</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>


    </header>
```

The CSS is

```
header .navbar {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

header .navbar a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f2663b;
}


.sprite_index_in_in_en_logo {
    margin-top: 35px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 138px;
    background: url(/img/koolindex_in.png?3b31f98c531cac850b1c866f36c9fc3bbdbfbd26) no-repeat -1010px -27px;
}
```

The problem occurs in google chrome but not in internet explorer. In internet explorer the page renders as expected.

Comment: It has to be enclosed in the <html> </html>  tag because <html> tag tells the browser that this is an HTML document.

Comment: My problem is part of a larger page. I now included more code. I might try and make a minimal working fiddle with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your class sprite_index_in_in_en_logo as mention below

```html
<style>
header .navbar {
    padding-top: 12px;
}

header .navbar a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    position: relative;
}

header h1 {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f2663b;
}


.sprite_index_in_in_en_logo 
{
margin-top: 35px;
width: 1024px;
height: 288px;
background: url(http://www.i2clipart.com/cliparts/4/8/0/e/clipart-simple-leaf-480e.png) no-repeat 0px;
}
</style>
<h1 id="logo" class="sprite_index_in_in_en_logo spritetext"></h1>




<header>  

    <nav class="navbar nohistory">
        <ul class="inlined">
            <li>
                <a href="/">{% trans %}Home{% endtrans %}</a>
            </li>                 


            <li class="current">
                <a href="/customer_service.htm">{% trans %}Customer Service{% endtrans %}</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </nav>


</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with your *background* image. Try removing -1010px and -27px.

For eg :

```html
background: url(http://www.addnectar.co.in/ovenfresh/ovenfresh/images/gif1.gif) no-repeat;
```

Demo : 
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4dtsb3s/)